# How to get decimal value?

Tags: c#, math, decimal, timespan

I am measuring serverPerformance.

Right now I get this in milliseconds but I want to convert this into seconds when it is more or equal to 500 milliseconds.

**I Accomplish this like this**

```
   public static string ConvertMillisecondsToSeconds(long milliseconds)
    {
        if(milliseconds >= 500)
            return Math.Ceiling(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds).TotalSeconds).ToString() + "s";

        return milliseconds.ToString() + "ms";
    }
```

**My problem**

When I return totalseconds without Math.ceiling I get for example:
0,846 seconds
When I use math.Ceiling method I get 1 second.

**Desiered result**

> 0,8 seconds.

basically im searching for a method that will return a decimal value, with 2 decimals.

Comment: Math.Round(seconds,2)

Comment: I actually tried Math.round but without the second paramater:(. 
Shame on me, thank you!

Comment: What you ask is called rounding. To round a number, you need the `Round` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var milliseconds = 0.846;
milliseconds.ToString("0.00"); // Gives 0.85
```

Comment: Got my answer in the comments but this works aswell